# Image Control in Wpf showing previous image which was deleted

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image control which is showing the preview image. If the user delete the image (which resides in folder) it should show the newly taken image.
but the image control shows the deleted image instead of showing new image.

```
// clear the image source before deleting the image.

// save image in the directory
public string globalFilePath;

int imageCount = Directory.GetFiles(imgDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;

string filePath = Path.Combine(imgDir, "IMAGE_" + ++imageCount + ".jpeg");
globalFilePath = filePath;

// setting image control source

var strUri = new Uri(WebCamControl.globalFilePath, UriKind.Relative);
previewImage.Source = BitmapFromUri(strUri);

//Method
public static ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = source;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
    }

// delete image

previewImage.Source =  null; 

if (System.IO.File.Exists(WebCamControl.globalFilePath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(WebCamControl.globalFilePath);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("File Not Exists");
}
```

After deleting the image in the directory file the image image control should show the new image, but my Image control  shows the deleted image. please give me the solution.

Comment: It will show the new Image after successfully loading that. This code does not show how/when the _next_ image is loaded.

Comment: after deleting the image in the file system, the new image will be taken and its get saved by default. i get that path and assigning it to the source of image control. @Henk

Comment: i found the problem that i save the new image with the same name which was as deleted image's name, i have changed the way of creating the name for new image. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, we generally don't need to use actual `BitMapImage` objects to display an `Image`. It's far easier to let the .NET Framework convert our `string` file paths to the images to the actual `Image` elements.

Also, it is *far* better to data bind the `Image.Source` to a property that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) (or a `DepenedencyProperty`):

```
<Image Source="{Binding YourImageFilePath}" ... />
```

Then, whenever a file path of a new image is set to the `YourImageFilePath` property, your displayed image will update immediately.

```
YourImageFilePath = filePath;
```

Comment: actually am not aware of that INotifyPropertyChanged interface or  DepenedencyProperty . can u please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I added a link to MSDN for `INotifyPropertyChanged` in answer.

Comment: i am implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged in my class itself like       (public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged) is it rite?

Comment: You need to implement it in whatever class your properties are declared, so that you can notify when their value(s) change.

Comment: i have implemented Inotifypropertychanged interface but the Image control shows nothing. i have created Image conerter to convert the images, but even no use. @sheridan

Answer (score -1):

Try This one:

```
    string path = ((BitmapImage)img.Source).UriSource.LocalPath;
img.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, null);
File.Delete(path);
```

OR

```
string path = ((BitmapImage)img.Source).UriSource.LocalPath;
img.Source = null;
File.Delete(path)
```